# Errors prevented isopacket load: While loading isopacket `constraint-solver`: Cannot call method 'slice' of null

Tags: meteor

When launching my meteor app with the following command:

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/vision-test" PORT=8282 ROOT_URL="sertal.esb.local:8383" meteor -p 8383
```

I get following error:

```
Errors prevented isopacket load:              

While loading isopacket `constraint-solver`:
packages/meteor/url_server.js:11:1: Cannot call method 'slice' of null
at Meteor.absoluteUrl.options (packages/meteor/url_server.js:11:1)
at <runJavaScript-2>:1109:4
at <runJavaScript-2>:1194:3
```

The same error appears when I use the parameters to run the built application.

Answer (score 6):

the `ROOT_URL="sertal.esb.local:8383"` parameter is missing the `http://` part. The `http://` or `https://` part of the `ROOT_URL` is mandatory

Comment: You just saved me several hours of headache. Thank you!!